# Simple app for URL bookmarking?

Tags: iphone, bookmarks, url

I'm looking for web service or an app (or whatever) for iphone 5 for bookmarking urls from google chrome or safari browser. I don't want to use bookmarks integrated into these browsers.

Does anybody know something simple and easy to use service / app with web frontend where i can work with these bookmarks? E.g. bookmarking via e-mail message is probably the simplest way for me.

Answer (score 2):

I'm quite pleased with [Pinboard](http://pinboard.in/). There are a number of [browser extensions and apps that work with the API](http://pinboard.in/resources/).

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly what you're describing, but have you considered Instapaper? It has a simple javascript bookmarklet to make saving pages from Safari or Chrome easy, it has an app and a web interface that are both very solid, and it gives you stripped-down versions of every bookmark, for easier reading, as well as normal links. Could end up being what you're looking for.

[Instapaper](http://instapaper.com/%22Instapaper%22)

Answer (score 0):

You can try out [Pocket](http://getpocket.com). It comes with browser extension which enables you to save your url to Pocket and also a native app on iOS for your reading pleasure.